# What is the source of Rey's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the closing scene of RoS Rey has a black lightsaber, where'd she get it, and if its not important why was there a close up on it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Her new lightsaber is something she built herself, with a unique yellow/orange blade, neither the blue/green of the Jedi, nor the red of the Sith and containing a yellow crystal rather than a white/red crystal that has changed colour for Rey. The VFX team refer to the hue as "*[Yellow optimism](https://www.insider.com/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-rey-new-lightsaber-explained-2020-1)*" and stressed that this isn't a colour that has been seen before.

[image]

She's integrated it into a hilt made from her old staff, reflecting her former life as a scavenger. For the same reason, it may contain some elements from Luke and Leia's lightsabers.

> Her lightsaber glowed white-gold, and she gazed at it a long moment.
> It was single-bladed, with an outer casing and emitter salvaged from
> her quarterstaff. The final result felt like the exact inverse of the
> lightsaber held by the dark Rey of her vision, and she loved it. It
> was beautiful, it fit so perfectly in her hand, and she would carry it
> with her forever.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

- Yellow lightsabers have appeared in canon before, relating to [Jedi Temple Guardians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_Guard), but there's no obvious reason to assume that this is why Rey's blade is this colour.
- The clear symbolism is that Rey is now a fully fledged Jedi Knight, having [constructed her own lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate_Trials) rather than merely using one she's been given.

Comment: Pretty confident it contains no components of Ren's saber since he threw it into the ocean.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov People with Force powers can pull X-Wings up out of the ocean.  It's not completely inconceivable that Ren's saber could have been recovered.

Comment: The two cases we have of X-Wings being pulled out of the ocean, it was from a known location out of pretty calm water. Ren threw his saber into a wildly tempestuous ocean. It’s not about anyone’s ability to raise something out of water. It’s the difference between driving your car into a small pond and throwing your cell phone into the ocean in the middle of a hurricane.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - I'm sure you can just sense it with the Force

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: While I don’t think there’s anything to prove or disprove components of Luke’s and Leia’s sabres being used in Rey’s, I don’t actually think she would do that. She revered both of them, especially Leia, and she buried their sabres on Tatooine as a mark of respect. Taking components from them first doesn’t seem like it would fit her character; I think she would have seen that as disrespectful rather than an homage.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Given that she expertly repaired his lightsaber from the previous film, it's likely that she would know how they work and could replicate the parts. That being said, bits like power cells are hardly sacred to a Jedi. Qui-Gon gives some to Anakin to fuel his podracer

Comment: @Valorum I’m certain she’d be able to do it, and I have little doubt that Luke and Leia would both have been perfectly happy to donate bits themselves. But I think, given Rey’s personality and her relationship with them both, she would feel wrong taking even small parts from their sabres after their deaths. When she repairs and uses Luke’s sabre (hesitantly, if I recall correctly), it’s with Leia’s express permission. Now they’re both dead, taking bits from their sabres would, I would guess, feel like taking your nan’s jewels off her before putting the coffin in the ground.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Rey is a scavenger who knows the value of a good part. She's recycled her staff (twice) and would undoubtedly have taken bits of both lightsabers rather than scrabbling around for parts from elsewhere

Comment: What would be the point of reverently wrapping and then burying the light sabers if she'd already cannibalized them for parts? I see no reason to think she would have used parts from those two sabers and many reasons to believe she wouldn't have.

Comment: @terdon - The *philosophically* important bits are the hilt and the crystal. Everything else is just electronics. Without access to a Jedi school, some of those parts (especially the high-energy power cells) are incredibly difficult to come by. I see no good reason why Rey wouldn't have had a few bits out of them rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Valorum so, first she'd cannibalize them and then make a whole show of reverently hiding them? Unless you have some sort of canon source for this, it's idle and, IMO, unconvincing speculation. And not in any way relevant to the answer, really.

Comment: @terdon - She's not *hiding* them, she's burying them. In the same place that the other Skywalkers are buried.

Comment: The Rise of Skywalker visual dictionary says that the quarter staff is from a ‘salvaged power conduit’ - so possibly she recharged it to use as a power source?

Comment: Didn't some of the Jedi at Geonosis have yellow lightsabers?

Comment: @RichS - Blues, greens and a purple; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1Prhh204Bc