# What color is Rey's new lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, we see Rey has a new lightsaber at the end of the film:

[image: Rey with a lightsaber]

Based on this image (and my memory from seeing the film), I would've said this lightsaber's blade was orange or maybe gold. However, I've seen people refer to it as being yellow.

Is there anything from Lucasfilm or the filmmakers of *The Rise of Skywalker* that says what the color of her lightsaber is?

Comment: Quora:https://www.quora.com/What-does-orange-mean-in-lightsabers/answer/Benjamin-Johnson-11 






by seeing the list, Rey's character isn't like a Jedi Sentinel so the lightsaber couldn't be yellow. Orange is what reflects her character (from the list); Golden, I don't think I have read/seen about a lightsaber that's golden.

Comment: FWIW I've only ever heard it referred to as yellow and/or gold but never orange until you've said it.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225128/what-is-the-source-of-reys-lightsaber

Comment: That is **amber**.  It is a low-pressure-sodium lightsaber.  Presumably they use Jedi tech so it doesn't take 10 minutes to warm up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the source of Rey's lightsaber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225128/what-is-the-source-of-reys-lightsaber) - the answer there mentions the same "yellow optimism" color which is given in the duplicate answer below

Comment: @Jenayah Linked and related but not a duplicate. That's asking where she got it, what it's made of etc. This is asking what colour it is.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it happens to cover this question as well, so yes dupe IMO.

Comment: @Jenayah _"The saber is made from an existing kyber crystal and her staff"_ vs _"it's yellow"_. Whilst I generally agree with the answers make dupes and litmus test policy we have going on here on SFF I think this is pushing it a bit too far. The answer mentions it as an aside and it isn't relevant in actually answering the question there.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica This is an unappreciated gem of a comment :)

Answer (score 19):

It is "golden yellow" according to Industrial Light & Magic's (ILM) visual effects supervisor, Patrick Tubach and the rest of the team there.

> **Is there a specific name to Rey's lightsaber color? We're going with 'yellow optimism.'**
>
> "That specific color yellow, if you go too pale — this is getting really in the weeds here — if you go too pale and you make it too light, it's going to look white a lot of times," Industrial Light & Magic (ILM) visual effects supervisor Patrick Tubach said of one factor that helped them land on that precise color. "Colors on film, sometimes they bleed away depending on the exposure and the quality of the light in the scene."
>
> "Making it that more golden yellow gives you that optimistic feeling, and it also allows you to make it supersaturated and still feel like it's in the 'Star Wars' universe," he added.
>
> [...]
>
> When asked if they had a specific name for the color, optimism was a word that came up frequently to describe the tone they were going for with the look of Rey's lightsaber.
>
> "We definitely went for things like golden and sun and optimism," said Tubach.
>
> "I think the optimism carried that choice," added Guyett.
>
> <sub>[Insider, The 'Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker' visual effects team explain Rey's new lightsaber and the small detail you may have missed in it](https://www.insider.com/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-rey-new-lightsaber-explained-2020-1)</sub>

Of note is that apparently the kyber crystal was already yellow when it came to Rey:

> **Rey's lightsaber does include a yellow kyber crystal**
>
> "Yeah, it's supposed to be a yellow crystal," said Tubach.
>
> <sub>[Insider, The 'Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker' visual effects team explain Rey's new lightsaber and the small detail you may have missed in it](https://www.insider.com/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-rey-new-lightsaber-explained-2020-1)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition) describes it as "*white-gold*"

> Her lightsaber **glowed white-gold**, and she gazed at it a long moment.

The film's [junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_A_Junior_Novel), rather less poetically, refers to it as "*yellow*".

> The **yellow-bladed lightsaber** she had built would honor their legacy.